# Crash around pthreads while integrating SQLite into RTP application on VxWorks

Tags: sqlite, embedded, pthreads, vxworks

I am trying to integrate SQLite library into RTP application on VxWorks. I built SQlite and link against it statically. I run simple test that works well on other systems. The test is realy primitive one: sqlite_open(), sqlite_exec(), sqlite_close(). Parameters are correct (works on other systems).

I experience SIGSEGV (signal code 11). I traced down to the point of crash with "printf()s" and discovered that it crashes after pthread_mutex_lock() call. What is interesting - it returns from the function call and then crashes. I checked the stack size (having a taskDelay() afore actual crash). Stack is big enough and far from its limit.

I try to build SQlite with **SQLITE_HOMEGROWN_RECURSIVE_MUTEX** and without. And I build all the time with **SQLITE_THREADSAFE 1**.

If someone has experienced something like that and managed to fix it - please let me know.

Here are few details, jut to outline them.

- VxWorks wersion: 6.8
- SQlite sources: 3.7.16.1
- Development environment: Windriever
- CPU Architecture: PowerPC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have found it. I had no pthreads in my VxWorks OS. Now it works.

The strange thing is that there is no way to verify that while building an application against pthreads library.

There is no easy way to do that, but at least some kind of "stub" function, rhater than SIGSEGV. Or am I asking too much for that kind of money?