# Is it possible to port recent SQLite to VxWorks 6.8?

Tags: sqlite, vxworks

I am struggling while trying to port recent SQLite sources to VxWorks 6.8. The architecture is PPC.

I made a separate topic ([Crash around pthreads while integrating SQLite into RTP application on VxWorks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970387/crash-around-pthreads-while-integrating-sqlite-into-rtp-application-on-vxworks)) to provide all details about the particular problem I am experiencing at the moment. But it looks like the problem is too specific and requires some amount of certain experience (porting C code to different platforms, pthreads, SQLite, knowledge of VxWorks).

So, I decided to just get a confirmation that it is doable at all. I mean it is doable for sure but I need to know that someone has actually succeeded with it within some reasonable time frame.

Please respond only if you yourself accomplished this. No general suggestions, like: "VxWorks is POSIX, SQLite is C - should not be a problem".

To moderators: I don't mean to duplicate my question. I am just norrowing it down and intend to close if no constructive ansver(s) appear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have figured it out - it was the problem in dosFS. I formatted the flash to HRFS and was able to run SQLite.

I had few porting issues on the way, something that is really platform-dependent. One familiar with POSIX functions should be able to figure it out.

I guess there is a problem with dosFS. So for now I will stick to HRFS.

In case of any questions about the porting itself - just contact me, may be I had te same and fixed.

Just for informaiton, I am using PPC and VxWorks 6.8.

Regards

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing (PPC, VxWorks 6.8, SQLite) and have a few questions:
1- Instead of into an RTP, I would like to put it into the DKM. Have you tried this?
2- Did you ever have to do manual changes to the _sqlite3.c_ code? (for example the isDelete symbol)
3- Did you have to do any manual changes to the code at all?

Comment: Perhaps your problem with dosFs was that it is not a power-fail safe, transactional based, file system like HRFS. I've had performance issues and general problems with HRFS in the past though. (After power failure it created huge read-only backup files of the disk that I couldn't delete without reformatting the flash). I'm very happy using Datalight RelianceFs now, but you have to assume the costs...

Comment: @pmb 1. I never tried to build SQlite for DKM. It would be interesting to try though, I have no need for this currently. May be you can share your experience ? Will help as much as I can. 2. Yes, I played with the code quite extensively. But it is nothing special, really. Just post build errors you have. 3. see answer "2". I guess this is not a good place for this topic. This is QA board - not a discussion forum. We probably should go on somewhere more SQLite-related (suggestions ?). SQLite mailing list, or something ?

Comment: @pmb It is interesting to test SQLite on that "Datalight RelianceFs". It is always nice to have an option. For now I can only run on HRFS.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The SQLite mailing list sounds good. A colleague of mine has already posted there http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Port-SQLite-to-VxWorks-6-8-td68430.html

Comment: @pmb Right! Answered there. Let's not poluted this topic anymore.